# insert data from a table and insert into another table in different database

Tags: php, database, insert

I have 2 database that link together. I need to retrieve data from that table and insert those column into a table in different database based on their Unique id number.

```
<?php

$handle  =  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

  mysql_query("USE shop",$handle);
  $query = "SELECT ModelCode,Class FROM shopfloor_pro WHERE CommNo = '0985560712'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
      $variable1 = $data->ModelCode;
      $variable2 = $data->Class;

      mysql_query("USE vt",$handle); 
      $sql = "INSERT INTO track SET
              t_model_code = '$variable1',
t_class = '$variable2' WHERE t_comm_no = '0985560712'";
       if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
       echo '<p>Error adding data into database: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>';
      }
      mysql_query("USE paintshop",$handle);

  }



?>
```

[this is the data that i want to retrieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jn9N.png)

[this is where i want to put the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azLtb.png)

When i run the code it shows 
"Error adding data into database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE t_comm_no = '0985560712'' at line 3"

Comment: Mysql_* has been removed from PHP, you need to modernize and move away from very old and insecure extension.

Comment: Im sorry, i'm not understand what you means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most likely do this in a single query - but as pointed out the `mysql` api has been deprecated a long time ago and totally removed from PHP 7+.

To do the query in a single operation you might try like this:

```
insert into `vt`.`track` (`t_model_code`,`t_class` )
    select `ModelCode`,`Class` from `shop`.`shopfloor_pro` where `CommNo`='0985560712'
```